# Send email from a textview

Tags: android, email

I got this code

```
if (!dataSet.get(listPosition).getEmail().equals("")) { //If email is not empty then send email

                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,dataSet.get(listPosition).getEmail());
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello");
                sendIntent.setType("text/html");
                v.getContext().startActivity(sendIntent);
            }
        }
    });
```

But when i press to send the email it doesn't have the email address i want to send it(only the text "hello").

Comment: Are you able to get email from _dataSet.get(listPosition).getEmail()_?

Comment: Yes i am doing        ` textViewEmail.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getEmail());` and it shows the email

Comment: Put a breakpoing on the first `if` statement - and check what you are actually sending.

Comment: Then get email direct from textview instead of list otherwise put breakpoint and check

Comment: If i get the email from the textview on my textview i will see the whole email and i just want to see the word "email" and press on it to send the email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto",dataSet.get(listPosition).getEmail(), null));
```

And remove this :

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,dataSet.get(listPosition).getEmail());
```

Comment: Thank you!Just edit it and delete the "" from dataSet.get... :D

Answer (score 0):

You should get the email from the TextView directly.